# Always show scrollbar in <select> on IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

The following code produces a listbox with 10 options.

```
<div style="overflow-y:scroll;">
    <select name="selectbox" size="4"  id="selectbox" >
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>7</option>
        <option>8</option>
        <option>9</option>
        <option>10</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

On chrome or IE8, i have this result, as you can see, the scrollbar is enabled.
[image: scroll visible]

But on IE11, I have not the same result

[image: scroll invisible]

The scrollbar is enabled only if the size is higher or equals than 6 :

[image: scroll BACK]

I want to have the scrollbar even if size is less than 6 on IE11, how can I do ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: did you try without the overflow?

Comment: Yes i try, same result

Comment: Just how critical is this to your site design? Really? This kind of thing is browser and platform dependant -- you cannot guarantee that it's going to look the same across all platforms (have you even tried looking at it in Safari on a Mac yet? Let alone any mobile plaforms?). The behaviour you're seeing is likely not something you can change. It will be different between different browsers, even different versions, and certainly across different platforms. My advice to you is to accept it. That's just how these things work.

Comment: Simba, it is a web application just for IE. So I don't need to know how it will be on different browsers.In professional world, there are requirements that we are obliged to respect

Answer (score 0):

If there is nothing to scroll how would you calculate the size of the scrollbar? Shouldn't it be 100%? You may concider using a fully styleable select box plugin.